# Including Author and/or Copyright info in pictures

Tags: photos, exif

Is there any way, when taking photos with Windows Phone, to automatically include my name as the author and maybe also a copyright statement into the EXIF information that is embedded in the image?

This would then allow this information to show up in the image details:

[image: Details tab of Properties box]

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible with the stock camera app or with Nokia Camera. You 'd have to look for an an alternative camera app which supports that - unfortunately I don't know any.

You can suggest this features on [http://windowsphone.uservoice.com](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions) as well.

Comment: Thank you for the idea to enter it at Windows Phone Uservoice. I found [a suggestion there that was similar](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4232591-add-user-option-to-include-owner-name-in-photo-e) and gave it 3 of my upvotes.